# Swift xcode error: "Cannot assign value of type 'SendEmailToVerifyPassword' to type 'MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate?'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

The purpose of my project is to have a login/create account screen and the user clicks a button to have an email sent to them with their username & password to verify it.

NOTE: username, password, and email are global variables declared in a different class of my project
EDIT: someone said to add something to the end of the file? What does that even mean? Can someone please help?

Screenshot of error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ikzS.png)

SendEmailToVerifyPassword class:

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI
class SendEmailToVerifyPassword: MFMailComposeViewController
{
    func ViewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
        let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self // Extremely important to set the --mailComposeDelegate-- property, NOT the --delegate-- property

        mailComposerVC.setToRecipients([email])
        mailComposerVC.setSubject("Your password/username verification")
        mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Hello.\n Your username is: \(username)\n Your password is \(password)", isHTML: false)

        return mailComposerVC
    }

    func showSendMailErrorAlert() {
        let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Could Not Send Email", message: "Your device could not send e-mail.  Please check e-mail configuration and try again.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        sendMailErrorAlert.show()
    }

    func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {

        switch result.rawValue {

        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled.rawValue:
            print("Cancelled mail")
        case MFMailComposeResultSent.rawValue:
            print("Mail Sent")
        default:
            break
        }
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }



}
```

Screenshot of storyboard button viewcontroller (click here is the button I want to activate the email):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Wlw6.png)

Comment: add this to the end of the file? `extension SendEmailToVerifyPassword: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {}`

Comment: Which line is the "end of the file"?

Comment: end of file means the the last line

Comment: after the last bracket will result in an error if I put "extension SendEmailToVerifyPassword: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {}" there it will treat "extension" as an unresolved identifier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class SendEmailToVerifyPassword: MFMailComposeViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate
{
...
}
```